# Why is pipreqs throwing the invalid syntax error (python)?

Tags: python, package, requirements.txt

I'm trying to create a requirements.txt file for my python project.

Why is pipreqs throwing the invalid syntax error? I tried modifying the path name multiple ways but am always thrown this error.

```
import pipreqs

pipreqs C:\\Users\\Aman\\Desktop
  File "<ipython-input-853-717ca401b58e>", line 1
    pipreqs C:\\Users\\Aman\\Desktop
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That simply isn't valid Python syntax. It looks like you should execute this in a command prompt, not in Python.

Comment: Can pipreqs be executed inside my python IDE?

Comment: If it has a command prompt, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be executing this in command prompt. It should look something like so:

`pipreqs C:\Users\Aman\Desktop`